# How can i convert an address int to char * string

Tags: c, memory-address

I have a memory address integer like this 0x80480ac and i want to assign it a char * like this:

```
char *address="\x08\x04\x80\xac";
```

How can i do it?

Comment: If you want to just use that as a string, no different than "hello, world", then @haccks is correct, however if you actually need address to point at the memory location 0x800480ac for some reason (say it is a device register or something), then see my answer.

Comment: i want to treat it as array of byte

Comment: Ignoring that "byte" and "char" are not necessarily equivalent, if I am understanding you correctly, then what you have is correct.  For example `address[0] == 0x08`, `address[1] == 0x04` and so on.  On issue is that the signedness of "char" is implementation defined, so you might want to be specific, either `signed char *` or `unsigned char* `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for:

```
char * address = (char *)0x080480ac;
```